# How to specify maven command line options in POM file?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have a goal which will always run with certain parameters on. I don't want to specify them again and again and want to include in POM file so that even when another goal calls that goal then those parameters are considered for execution.

These parameters shouldn't be in global scope as they are just for test scope.

---

I have a code in spring-boot which uses profiles. If I run the test with the `-Dspring.profiles.active=TEST` expected outcome occurs. So to run `failsafe:integration-test` goal with `-Dspring.profiles.active=TEST` is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here: specify the active Profiles in the test that requires them:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("TEST")
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void testServiceInitialized() throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
```

this also allows the IDE to run the test directly.

Option two would be to let the failsafe plugin know to pass that -D parameter to the tests:

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#argLine

So either set a property "argLine" that contains this parameters or configure the plugin. With this approach those tests will only run using maven - in the IDE you may would have to reproduce this config - some are smart on will do this automatically.

If you also need to tell spring boot to enable some profiles the spring-boot plugin allows this directly: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html

Comment: The problem is that the same thing for running the main application fails saying `No active profiles found`

Comment: Not sure what error you encounter. ActiveProfiles is for tests only. If you have configurations that are only valid for certain profiles there is @Profile. If you need to enable some specific profile for the application do so via -D options on the command line or by activating them in the spring-boot maven plugin: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html (setting a property <run.profiles>). Is that an error from Spring? Since there is no requirement for a profile... or do you have everything into at least one @Profile? So no default beans at all?

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43626343/4669984). This question depicts the exact problem.

Comment: `-Drun.profiles` actually worked. I'm now looking to modify pom file where `springboot:run` and include that property. Thanks!

Comment: glad it helped :)