# How to manage maven profiles through annotations/pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-profiles

Ref - [Maven Profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43611622/4669984)

---

I don't want to specify profile through command line arguments while running. Because, if I change it locally, then changes have to be made thoughout CI stream.

---

**Scenario:**

There are basically two profiles `"PROD"` and `"TEST"`. I have annotated methods using these. Basically, I connect different databases under different profiles.

While the test classes are annotated with `@ActiveProfile("TEST")`

I run tests using `mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integraton-test` and run application using `mvn springboot:run`

---

**Problem:**

*Case 1:*
Issue: Only `PROD` related methods run for PROD and TEST.

If I don't use `@Profile("PROD")` and only use `@Profile("TEST")` and I use `@ActiveProfiles("TEST")` as specified in reference. Both mvn commands without any flag specified above only use the beans which are not annotated with profiles.

*Case 2:*
Issue: `PROD` doesn't run.

If I use both `PROD` and `TEST` without any flag, `mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integraton-test` command runs perfectly (only when `@ActiveProfile("TEST")` is specified otherwise I'd have to send a flag `-Dspring.profiles.active=TEST`) but `springboot:run` doesn't work as it cannot pick up any database configuration and no active profile found.

This is the case even when I Annotate PROD profiles with both PROD and `@Primary`

Surprisingly even If I provide command line argument the result is the same. `mvn springboot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=PROD`

If I annotate the main class where these profiles are run with `@ActiveProfiles("PROD")`, the result is the same.

---

*Ideal Scenario/Expected:*

To run tests using `mvn test-compile failsafe:integration-test` preferably without flag. (Already acheived but prod isn't working)

To run prod using `mvn springboot:run` emphasis of no flags.

---

*Preferable changes:*

Java annotations: Annotations such as `@Profile`, `@ActiveProfile`, `@Primary` which tells Spring-boot or maven what to use.

POM.xml: setting profiles for directing maven what to use.

Comment: If you are using `mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integraton-test` you seemed to have not understood the life cycle. Why not simply `mvn clean verify` (If you have correctly configured failsafe plugin)...Apart from that the @Profile is only for spring profiles but not for maven profile...

Comment: `mvn verify` runs unit tests too. I just want to run integration tests.

Comment: You are mixing Spring Profiles and Maven Profiles. Both are different things and serve a different purpose.

Comment: @M.Deinum But, `@Profile` and `@ActiveProfile` worked in the case of test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short i think you just need to add `spring.profiles.active=PROD` to your `application.properties`

I put together an example which prints the contents of a bean which differs between prod ant test, hope this helps.

When running the below code i get the following output:

`mvn spring-boot:run`: The String in the context is: PROD

`mvn clean test`: The String in the context is: TEST

ProfilesApplication.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProfilesApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProfilesApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private String profiledString;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProfilesApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("PROD")
    public String prodString() {
        return new String("PROD");
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("TEST")
    public String testString() {
        return new String("TEST");
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("The String in the context is: {}", profiledString);
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=PROD
```

ProfilesApplicationTests.java:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("TEST")
public class ProfilesApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```